# Get AS path from a file by regex

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regex to get as path information from the path.

The input line would be:

```
as path: 1 2 3 4.5 6 i (test)
```

I hope to get: `['1', '2', '3', '4.5', '6', 'i']`

I wrote the regex in Python:

```
re.findall(r'\b\d*[\.]?\d*\b|\bi\b', line)
```

But I failed to get the result I expected. What's wrong with my regex? Thank you!

Comment: Please explain more with some real examples.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|i)\b', line)`

Answer (score 0):

Since all the patterns in the first alternative can match empty strings (`?` and `*` may match 0 chars) your first alternative, `\b\d*[\.]?\d*\b`, actually matches any word boundary location.

You need to make it match at least 1 digit, so the following should work as expected:

```
re.findall(r'\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|i)\b', line)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BG0Kiq/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `|` - or

  - `i` - an `i` substring
- `)` - end of the alternative groups
- `\b` - a word boundary.